# Taking user-input for 3 variables using for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am a new learner of python and tried to take 3 or more variables to store different user-inputs using for loop but when I run it, it says the varibles are not defined.

```
for i in [p, q, r]:
    i = int(input("Enter any value="))

print("Your 1st value=", p)
print("Your 2st value=", q)
print("Your 3st value=", r)
```

Comment: Do the values need to be stored in p, q, r or could they stored in a list?

Comment: that's because python copy the value of p, q and r to make a list and then copy this list's element inside of the local `i` variable. You can achieve this kind of behaviour by creating an object like this :
`vals = ["l","p","q"]
obj = {}
for i in vals:
    obj[i] = int(input("Enter any value="))`

Comment: Ohh, this means this could be done only through arrays if i am not wrong.

Comment: What are `p`, `q`, `r` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
r = dict()
for i in range(3):
    r[i] = int(input("Enter any value="))

for i in range(3):
    print(f"Your {i} value = {r[i]}")
```

Comment: Can this be done without using arrays?

Comment: Yes, you can use list instead of dictionnary for example.

Comment: List is also an array, I mean can it be done without list,tuple,set or dict ?

Comment: You need to iterate someways. Otherwise you can replace the  loop by 3 successive instructions: p = .. ; q = ... r = ... ;